# C#: Integrating an existing control in a user control into another form using an Interface

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, factory-pattern

I have a user control/form having some controls (buttons, Groupboxes,...). I want to create an interface to let the user access these controls from its own form.
It means when he clicks a button in his form, it will be executed the content of a button in my form, like the following:

```
    void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        [some statements and preparation code]  
        using (var Dialog= new UserControlClass())
        {
            Dialog.Initialization();
            Dialog.ShowDialog(this);
        }
        [some statements code] 
     }
```

The user doe not have access to my code, I want only to let him access to my control using an interface, with keeping my code unchanged.
Is the factory the right solution for that, and how to do it?

Comment: Just create a **Public Method** in your UserControl, then the user will call that.  What issue are you having here?  An Interface certainly could be useful, but isn't necessary unless you have **multiple types of UserControls** that all need to be dealt with in the same manner?  As written, your question is detailed enough to need Interfaces/Factory Patterns.

Answer (score 1):

For example, assume, you have a user control like this. And you want to click to button1 from the parent form.

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
    }

    public void ShowDialog()
    {
        button1_Click(null, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

For make this, you can add a public function to the interface (for ex: `ShowDialog`) and call it from the main form like this.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myUserControl1.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: In `ShowDialog()`, don't call `button1_Click()` directly, instead use [button1.PerformClick();](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick(v=vs.110).aspx).